# System(s) freeze when Adaptec RAID BIOS loads

Tags: bios, raid, freeze, asus

I have an old RAID setup consisting of an ASUS P8H77-V with an Adaptec 6405 RAID Controller.  This setup has been working well for years.

Recently there were a fault in the UPS that resulted in the computer booting up a few times.

Since then as soon as the Adaptec BIOS installs the system freezes.

This is what I've tried / done:

- I can log into the Adaptec Controller by pressing (CTRL+A)
- If I disable Adaptec's Runtime BIOS option the computer works (The keyboard CAPS lock Led responds and I am able to go into the computer's BIOS)
- When I enable Adaptec's Runtime BIOS the computer freezes after I get the message that the RAID installed the BIOS. (Keyboard is not reactive and computer is in a frozen state)

I tried moving the raid controller to another MB (Asus P8H67) with exactly the same outcome.  I tried reinstalling the firmware on the Adaptec just in case it got corrupted.  I tried:

- v5.2 - 19176
- v5.3 - 19204

Any ideas what I could try / what I might be missing?

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Have you also tried different drives?

Comment: Try with other drives, or without any of the drives to check if it's the controller itself, or the drives that makes it freeze.

Comment: @svin83: Without drives that Adaptec BIOS does not get installed. The machine remains reactive

Comment: then try different drives

Comment: @mashuptwice:  I found a 4 old drives and initialized them as RAID 5. While the RAID is still rebuilding the system is no longer freezing.

So should I try swapping each drive in my existing raid with a new one and see whether this solves the issue?

I would like to avoid losing data

Comment: Best case would be to have a backup.
Second best would be if only one drive is hooped.
If two are broken, you got no chance to recover that data.
Best would be to check each drive on a second machine and isolate the broken one. Rebuilding 3 times generates too much stress for the drives and takes an eternity

Comment: Meanwhile I would like to recommend you ZFS

Comment: @mashuptwice: I can afford to loose data BUT if I can avoid it I would.

If I understand you correctly I should pull out each drive and test it.  I have Spinrite (GRC's utility) that I can use to check individual drives.  Would this be OK or do you recommend some other tool?

Thanks

Comment: Should be fine, any S.M.A.R.T. capable software should do

Comment: Thanks.  I will update once I've tested them all

Comment: @mashuptwice: The RAID I have is a RAID 5 made up of 4 x 1TB WD drives.  Since my last posting I sourced 4 replacment WD drives. Each drive was tested with HDDSCAN's SMART Extended self-test and all returned a passed status.  I replaced each drive one at a time, each time allowing the controller to rebuild the RAID.

After I had done that I started the computer with the 4th (last) drive unplugged.  The computer froze as soon as the Adaptec BIOS got installed.  In this setup none of the original drives were present.

I would be more than happy to try something else before I reinitialse.